# Using Supplier instead of Optional as a method parameter

Tags: java, overloading, option-type, null-check, supplier

I have an interface and its parameter can be `null`.

```
int count(@Nullable F filter);
```

To avoid `null` parameters and *null-checks*, common advice is to use the method overloading:

```
int count();
int count(@NonNull F filter);
```

In some cases, I don't like this approach, because it forces clients to make this kind of job:

```
F f = getFilter();
int count = f != null ? count(f) : count();
```

It much more convenient for client to use:

```
count(getFilter())
```

Optionals, at the first glance, can solve this problem but `Optional` should not be used for parameters https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3553

So my question is: can I use `Supplier` instead?

```
// service code:
int count(Supplier<F> filter) {
    Optional.ofNullable(filter.get()).map(f -> count(f)).orElseGet(() -> count());
};
//client code:
count(() -> getFilter())
```

Or even

```
int count(Supplier<Optional<F>> filter)
```

Idea doesn't show any warnings.

I personally like my code after that, but isn't it cheating? Why it's better than `Optional`?

**EDIT:** Thanks for comments. I agree, in my case `Supplier` is just a sophisticated `@Nullable` approach.

I will return to:

```
int count();
int count(@NonNull F filter);
/////
getFilter().map(f -> count(f)).orElseGet(() -> count());
```

Comment: Your first example of using a `Supplier<F>` is just a more complex way of using `@Nullable F`. You've just replaced the `@Nullable F` with something that can return a `@Nullable F`. The second example of using a `Supplier<Optional<F>>` is a nasty way to fool Idea.

Comment: *"Why it's better then Optional?"* it's not.

Comment: @RobSpoor ok, but do we have an approach to give a nice interface to a client and avoid null checks at the same time?

Comment: @Alexey if your method accepts nulls there's no way around it: you'll have to check whether the parameter is `null`.

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable` is not meant be used for `null`-checks, it's an abuse of Optional. Use **explicit** *null-check* (there's nothing wrong with it), instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the client-code to dial with `null`, you can change the method `getFilter()` to return `Optional<F>`.

In this case, the code in the client would look like that:

```
int count = getFilter().map(MyClass::count).orElse(MyClass.count());
```

With this approach, your method `count(F)` doesn't require any extra logic.

If it feels like too complicated, then can implement `count(F)` in such a way that it would delegate to `count()` in case if provided argument is `null`.

Both your attempt with `Supplier<F>` and `Supplier<Optional<F>>` are artificial and seem to be driven by intention to circumvent Sonar, rather than by the real use cases.